# Python: Nesting counters

Tags: python, iteration

For my customers, iterating through multiple counters is turning into a recurring task.

The most straightforward way would be something like this:

```
cntr1 = range(0,2)
cntr2 = range(0,5)
cntr3 = range(0,7)

for li in cntr1:
    for lj in cntr2:
        for lk in cntr3:
            print li, lj, lk
```

The number of counters can be anywhere from 3 on up and those nested for loops start taking up real estate.

Is there a Pythonic way to do something like this?

```
for li, lj, lk in mysteryfunc(cntr1, cntr2, cntr3):
    print li, lj, lk
```

I keep thinking that something in itertools would fit this bill, but I'm just not familiar enough with itertools to make sense of the options.  Is there already a solution such as itertools, or do I need to roll my own?

Thanks,
j

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is `itertools.product`

```
for li, lj, lk in itertools.product(cntr1, cntr2, cntr3):
    print li, lj, lk
```

Will do exactly what you are requesting. The name derives from the concept of a Cartesian product.

Comment: Further (in case someone with a slightly different problem arrives here): Suppose you have an array `cntr = [cntr1, cntr2, cntr3]`. Then calling `itertools.product(cntr)` won't work. (It just prints all 1-tuples where the first element is an element of `cntr`; effectively it prints `cntr`.) Instead, you can do `itertools.product(*cntr)`.