# How can I get rid of multiple nested for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops, python-3.2

I have a Python (3.2) script that searches for points with a property that I want. But it has this ugly part:

```
for x in range(0,p):
  for y in range(0,p):
    for z in range(0,p):
      for s in range(0,p):
        for t in range(0,p):
          for w in range(0,p):
            for u in range(0,p):
              if isagoodpoint(x,y,z,s,t,w,u,p):
                print(x,y,z,s,t,w,u)
              else:
                pass
```

Is there something I can do so that it looks a bit better?

Comment: The OP may find the answers to this question helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150467/python-nesting-counters

Comment: related: [Fast tensor rotation with NumPy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4962606/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html) to simplify your code:

```
from itertools import product

def print_good_points(p, dimensions=7):
    for coords in product(range(p), repeat=dimensions):
        args = coords + (p,)
        if isagoodpoint(*args):
            print(*coords)
```

That solves your problem as stated; however, I'm not sure that you really wanted to include `p` in the arguments to `isagoodpoint()` . If not, you can lose the line that adds it:

```
from itertools import product

def print_good_points(p, dimensions=7):
    for coords in product(range(p), repeat=dimensions):
        if isagoodpoint(*coords):
            print(*coords)
```

The lines in your code

```
else:
    pass
```

do nothing, by the way. Also, `range(0, p)` is equivalent to `range(p)`.

And ... just in case this use of `*` in function calls is unfamiliar to you:

http://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/expressions.html#index-34

Comment: Rather than `product(*repeat etc.)`, you could use `product(range(p), repeat=dimensions)` (i.e. use the `repeat` keyword argument instead of the `repeat` function).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something along the lines of:

```
for x, y, z in product(range(0,p), range(0,p), range(0,p)):
    print(x,y,z)
```

or

```
for x, y, z in product(range(0,p), repeat=3):
    print(x,y,z)
```

For `python2.7` you need to `from itertools import product`.